# The power for which the product of the digits is $n$ greater times the sum of the digits

Tags: number-theory

Find the smallest integer $n⩾2$ such that for some positive integer $k$ the product $p(n,k)$ of the digits of $n^k$ is equal to $ns(n,k)$ where $s(n,k)$ is the sum of the digits of $n^k$.

I considered first $n=2$. No small exponent $k$ works, so if it exist the number $2^k$ having that property must have at least $m≥6$ digits. The digits being on average equal to $4.5$ their product will be on the order of $P\approx(9/2)^{k}$ or $0$ if there is a ‘$0$’ digit, and the sum of the digit will be on the order of $S\approx9k/2$. This implies that, in general, $P>2S$ or $P=0<2S$ in the case where there is a $0$ digit. Equality seems hopeless. Same argument works for $n=3,4,5$.

For $6$ I found this example: $6^4=1296$. How can this be proven?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Is there any reason to imagine it has a better solution than a crude search?

Comment: Interesting question. Have you considered any analytical approaches? Did you get anywhere wiith them? I ask becaue this problem seems to lack some context like @lulupointed out. Did you encounter it while working with a particular topic or not?

Comment: Side note:  $n=1$ works, though it's not very interesting. $n=0$ as well.  So I suppose you meant to require that $n>1$?

Comment: @lulu, what about negative integers $n$?

Comment: @NaitikMundra  Well, yes.  But I assume the OP meant to require $n>1$.

Comment: The distribution of the decimal digits of $n^k$ seems pretty random, but AFAIK not much quantitative is known.

Comment: It looks to me like, for example, $5^k$ always has at least one $0$ digit for $k > 58$; in fact, it seems like at least one of the lowest $100$ digits is $0$ (for $k = 4081$, the $100$'th digit is the first that is $0$).  If that really is the case, it should be provable by a finite computation (but probably not one that is feasible in practice).